# How to flatten a RDD<List>?

Tags: java, apache-spark, flatten

I am fairly new to Spark and using Java to do functional programming with Casandra as datasource.
As an output of a map task I getting a list of strings.

```
JavaRDD<List<String>> crows = sessions.map(new Function<Session, List<String>>() {});
```

I want to convert variable crows from type   `JavaRDD<List<String>> to JavaRDD<String>` i.e. want to flatten out.
Can someone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: `flatmap` instead of `map`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to @UniLocal the following works:

```
JavaRDD<String> crows = sessions.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Session, String>() {
    public Iterable<String>  call(T x) {
        List<String> someList = ...
        return someList;
    }
});
```

Comment: @GaborBakos- Can you have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517621/how-to-access-objects-declared-and-initialized-outside-the-call-method-of-java