# How to access objects declared and initialized outside the call() method of JavaRDD

Tags: cassandra, closures, apache-spark

I am unable to access objects declared and initialized outside the call() method of JavaRDD.
In the below code snippet, call() method makes a fetch call to C* but since javaSparkContext is defined outside the call method scope so compiler give a compilation error.

```
stringRdd.foreach(new VoidFunction<String>() {
                @Override
                public void call(String str) throws Exception {
                    JavaRDD<String> vals = javaFunctions(javaSparkContext).cassandraTable("schema", "table", String.class)
                            .select("val");
                }
            });
```

In other languages I have used closure to do this but not able to achieve the same here. 
Can someone suggest how to achieve this in the current code context.

Comment: Are those objects referenced by `final` variables? That is a requirement in Java. (And they are better be immutable while you use them: https://speakerdeck.com/heathermiller/spores-distributable-functions-in-scala?slide=31)

Comment: I already made it work by making the variable final but I wanted to check if there is any elegant way to achieve this requirement in java.

Comment: I think that is a good and elegant solution in Java, there is nothing wrong with it. (Though I tend to use `final` for most places where applicable, so I might not be unbiased in this regard.)